# android map fragment in dialog fragment

Tags: android, dictionary, dialog, fragment

This is my xml code **dialogFragment.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text = "this is map"/>
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my JAVA code:

```
public class myDialog extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            getDialog().setTitle("Title");
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogFragment.xml, null);
            return v;
    }
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    }
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            super.onDismiss(dialog);
    }

    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            super.onCancel(dialog);
    }   
 }
```

When I am testing this code for the first time I am opening the dialog it works perfectly with map, but when I am clicking on back button and again opening button it stops working. But when I am removing map it works ok(never shows error).
So please help me to make the dialog fragment to work with map without error, thank you very much in advance.

This is the error log:

> 04-06 15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-06 15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): Process:
>   com.example.newapp, PID: 11391 04-06 15:15:57.434:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13393): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML
>   file line #86: Error inflating class fragment 04-06 15:15:57.434:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
>   04-06 15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 04-06
>   15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 04-06
>   15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 04-06
>   15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 04-06
>   15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   com.example.newapp.ReqDialog.onCreateView(myDialog.java:16) 04-06
>   15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700) 04-06
>   15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
>   04-06 15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
>   04-06 15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684) 04-06
>   15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
>   04-06 15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443) 04-06
>   15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 04-06
>   15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 04-06
>   15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 04-06 15:15:57.434:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 04-06
>   15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-06
>   15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 04-06 15:15:57.434:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   04-06 15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 04-06
>   15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 04-06 15:15:57.434:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13393): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #86:
>   Duplicate id 0x7f050079, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with
>   another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment 04-06
>   15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4791) 04-06
>   15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393): at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
>   04-06 15:15:57.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13393):
>
> [... 20 more]

Comment: Can you post Dialog creation code?

Comment: the android code is the Dialog creation code

Comment: No, I meant the code which shows the Dialog, that is creating a Dialog instance and invoking show method on it.

Comment: myDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "myDialog");

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: https://github.com/yurevich1/habrtimezone/blob/master/res/layout/agmap.xml#L6

I think you wrote wrong title in file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

I hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't help

Comment: Try to use ths project I gave at all. This is workable project.